# I hava a custom resource file which path is :app/values/defaults.xml in my app

Tags: android, xml, ide

I have defined a custom resource file which path is :app/res/values/defaults.xml in my app,but when i use the resources in other files,the IDE show me the error like the screenshot below.I have no idea how to solve this problem.

[android studio show me the error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5XF2.png)

[image]

Comment: you are using attributes that are not known to framework. Take out some time to learn how custom styles works.

Comment: have You defined that color inside Your color.xml?

Answer (score 0):

The error tell you that your color `cpb_default_color` its not create in `values/color` you must create first this variable in `values/colors` like this

```
<color name="cpb_default_color">#yourHexColor</color>
```

Hope to help!

Comment: i have also saw the same ways to define  custom resources files in open-source app,it includes different kinds of resource like color,dimen,string and so on.How does it handle this? So i want to use the same way.

Comment: i dont undestand you clearly ...how did you want to declare your resource.. android system has separated  folders for colors,strings,dimens  what is the problem to declare your variables in them?

Comment: <resources>
    <color name="cpb_default_color">#33b5e5</color>
    <dimen name="cpb_default_stroke_width">4dp</dimen>
    <integer name="cpb_default_min_sweep_angle">20</integer>
    <integer name="cpb_default_max_sweep_angle">300</integer>
    <item name="cpb_default_sweep_speed" format="float" type="string">1</item>
    <item name="cpb_default_rotation_speed" format="float" type="string">1</item>
</resources>         This is the custom resource file with the path /src/main/res/default.xml    @Kristiyan Varbanov

Comment: you want to store dimens,colors,string in one resource file am i right ?

Comment: hmm i don`t think that is a good idea to put all your resources in one file... if it is why android developers are created these folders like systems..

Answer (score -1):

You should place all your colors in colors.xml